# How to activate the virtual environment for python?

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

My website is hosted in a PAAS provider,

made a virtual environment using below command

$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 mysite-virtualenv

However I can not activate it, please refer the attached image for file structure.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your virtual environment was created with virtualenvwrapper. Activate it with command `workon mysite-virtualenv` in bash console on PythonAnywhere.

For the web app you need to set it on the "Web" configuration page.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in [official Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments), You can create the environment with:

```
python3 -m venv NAMENEV
```

and activate with:

```
NAMENEV\Scripts\activate.bat # ON WINDOWS
source NAMENEV/bin/activate # ON LINUX/MAC
```

Answer (score 0):

To activate the virtual environment in the terminal enter the following command:-
For Linux,

```
source envName/bin/activate
```

For windows,

```
envName/scripts/activate
```